# How to apply default theme on dialogs

Tags: android, dialog, android-theme

I have an application without any theme.
I want to keep the default android theme only on dialogs.

To do that I've created a custom Dialog (says MyDialog). Inside the constructor, I've put:

```
public MyDialog() {
    if (getAndroidVersion() >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL,
                android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog_NoActionBar);
}
```

but when the dialog is showed up, it does not have any theme. Infact, testing on Android 4.2 the dialog appears with the old android theme.

How can i show dialog with current version look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) class to build your dialogs. Use `AlertDialog.Builder(Context context, int theme)` to set dialog theme.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is by assigning a certain `style` to the created `Dialog` :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, R.style.Theme_Dialog);
```

and then, define your theme in `styles.xml` which is in **values** folder:

```
  <style name="Theme_Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme">   <!-- or whatever Theme you want -->
     <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
     <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  </style>
```

and for your case here (The default app theme) , just go to `AndroidManifest.xml` (**Application** tab), then look for **Theme** under **ApplicationAttributes**, it will be a direct **system_theme** or a theme from **project-resources** and if so, know it's name and you will find it stored in the `styles.xml` files under that name.